# Detect how non-full screen WebApp was loaded (Home Screen v. Safari)

Tags: iphone, web-applications, mobile, mobile-safari

It's easy to detect how a full-screen WebApp (i.e., WebApps that include `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`) was launched – just check `window.navigator.standalone`

Is it possible to do the same for a non-full screen WebApp?

I want to show the user a "bookmark this web page" bubble (like on http://youtube.com), but I don't want to show it if the web page was launched from the home screen.

I'm pretty sure this is possible since YouTube is a non-full screen WebApp and it doesn't show the "bookmark me!" bubble when its launched from the home screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at the youtube website url opened in the Safari, in the last part of the url, there has a home/?bmb=1, i think that bmb=1 is actually making the difference, when you bookmark this page, the url will include this bmb variable, then when you press the home web button, on the server side you can detect this and know it is from home web button.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the right approach. Youtube.com adds a hash parameter before you bookmark, and if you load the site with that hash parameter it knows you launched it from the bookmark.

Comment: Oh well, if you look at the fourth comment of my answer, that's exactly what I wrote. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something in your question, but: `window.navigator.standalone` is telling if the app is **currently** in full screen mode or not (if the browser supports this property at all).

That means: if the property is there and it is false, you might want to offer your bookmark button. If it is there and true, don't show it (app is already bein run from home screen). If the property is missing, don't show the bookmark button because the user agent does not support it.

Try to visit www.luscarpa.com for instance. Use Safari and then bookmark it to your home screen and notice the difference.

It also has info about the fullscreen mode (that's where I have learned about it): http://www.luscarpa.com/development/make-your-website-an-iphone-web-application/

Comment: I can't add `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` to my web app b/c it needs the Safari controls to work (specifically I don't want to implement my own back / forward button bar)

Since I'm not using this meta tag, `window.navigator.standalone` will never be true. I'm wondering whether there's *another way* to determine whether my application was launched via a home screen bookmark

Comment: Have you actually tried reading window.navigator.standalone if the meta tag is missing? From the documentation I cannot see that it would required the meta tag.

Comment: A more basic approach would be to use "<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">". This is triggered only when started from home screen. Replace startup.png with a non-cachable dynamic page that spits out an image but also stores the session ID of the request. On your first "real" page check, if the session ID was saved whilst calling the start image. If yes, you must be in full screen mode. Just a thought. Have not tried that.

Comment: And yet another thought: the meta tag is only valid for the first page. So, let your start page have the meta tag and detect the standalone property. Then redirect the user to the "2nd" start page and pass a parameter whether the first page was started from home screen or not. On the 2nd page don't use the meta tag. If your parameter is not set, ask the user if he wants to add your app to the home screen.

Comment: @Krumulur – the `<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">` tag doesn't do anything unless there's also a `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` tag

Answer (score 2):

```
if ('standalone' in navigator && !navigator.standalone && (/iphone|ipod|ipad/gi).test(navigator.platform) && (/Safari/i).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
        document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="add2home.css">');
        document.write('<script type="application/javascript" src="add2home.js"><\/s' + 'cript>');
}
```

that's a little script that came from [cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) seems to get the job done

of course, if you're not using the add2home script then you should change the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Horace, you can study Google's commented javascript source code, which appears they may have used in their YouTube bubble detection scheme, at
http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble